# Android - Set start activity for android Tab

Tags: android, android-layout, tabs

I have a  simple Tablayout for four activites. 
This is it's xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"

    >
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/bg1"
            />
        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:layout_marginBottom="-4dp"
            />
    </LinearLayout>
</TabHost>
```

When it starts the activity connected to tab0 starts by default

What I need is to create start layout before any activity starts to look like the following
! [] http://i49.tinypic.com/2ugf3op.png

I don't know where I should put the layout of the activity

Comment: Are you going for something like splash screen?

Comment: It's not a splash screen because the tabs are in the bottom. I want the read screen to be at the begining and when I click on a tab the activity connected to it start

Comment: You should possibly create the read screen as first (additional) tab, then if a user clicks any other tab, you just remove the first tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default in android, always the first tab is selected by default. What you can do to confuse the user that nothing is selected is that you change the drawables of the tabs. Make all tabs unselected by default, and in the frame layout you set the content as in image. Then as soon as the user clicks on the tab then change the color of that tab and then start the activity. The activity connected to tab0 will start by default always. But you can make a check condition there, that if the user has not clicked on anything then display some empty screen with background or otherwise start the activity.

**UPDATE**
By default open up some empty activity with some views according to your wish. This will be shown as soon as the user opens up the activity with the tabs. Then you can implment `OnTabChangeListener` on that activity and overide the `onTabChanged()`

```
  public void onTabChanged(String tabId) {
            if (tabId.equals("TAB 0")) {
                  // Show your actual activity here
            } 
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. You say the activity connected to tab0 will start by default always, I can't get how to make it doesn't start ?

Comment: If I opened  up some empty activity with some views , the tabs willnot be visisble on the screen.